# How to declare a CAPnPROTO builder before initialzing it in c++?

Tags: c++11, capnproto

I am new to CAP'N PROTO. I have created cap'n proto a structure and part of structure mentioned below:

```
**struct InjectorRequestMsg {
dataFrame @0: InjectorDataFrame;  
injectorRequestID @1: UInt32;
injectorID @2: UInt32;
injectorScriptPath @3: Text;
injectorFuncName @4: Text;
injectorLogPath @5: Text;
```

}**

Then, I am writing a builder in my C++ code as follows:
**`::capnp::MallocMessageBuilder message;
InjectorRequestMsg::Builder injectorRequestMsg = message.initRoot<InjectorRequestMsg>();`**

Then, subsequent allocations also working fine and I am able to set all the values.
But, when I try to declare and initialize InjectorRequestMsg::Builder like
**`InjectorRequestMsg::Builder injectorRequestMsg;
injectorRequestMsg = message.initRoot<InjectorRequestMsg>();`**

Then, it gives below error:
capnproto/InjectorMessage.capnp.h:197:3: error: declared here
   Builder() = delete;  // Deleted to discourage incorrect usage.

Hence, could you please help me to understand how can I declare and initialize InjectorRequestMsg::Builder injectorRequestMsg in two different steps, so that I will make InjectorRequestMsg::Builder injectorRequestMsg as data-member of a C++ class and all member functions of C++ class can access it?

Comment: From the message you simply can't do it in two steps. I *think* you are asking about class members, you don't need `injectorRequestMsg = message.initRoot<InjectorRequestMsg>();` in a constructor, look at [member initialisation lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
InjectorRequestMsg::Builder injectorRequestMsg = nullptr;
```

The Cap'n Proto library often forces you to explicitly initialize to `nullptr` as a way to say: "I'm not ready to initialize this yet." It especially wants this for types that will crash the process if used uninitialized, to make it hard to screw up. In contrast, `Reader` types don't need to be explicitly initialized, because the default constructor can initialize the `Reader` to represent the struct's default value.